# Shorter way to check that value of multiple input is empty for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-input

```
let a = $('#plustitle').val().trim();  // input type text
let b = $('#plustags').val().trim(); // input type text
let c = $('#plustory').val().trim(); // textarea
```

I need to check if any of the above variable is empty, i.e. have value "";

Using jquery `each` loop - there is a lot of code.

Is there a way to do it in a shorter way.

Comment: Sorry, you've made me insecure about my logic but it was correct^^ `!a || !b` is the same as `!(a && b)` and therefore `if(!(a && b && c))`

Comment: @Andreas, I see, pls place the answer, I think there is no shorter way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we use the fact that an empty string will be [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) we could achieve your requirement with

```
if (!(a && b && c)) {
  // one of them is empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could abstract it the following way:

```
function isEmpty(id) {
  return ($('#' + id).val().trim() == '');
}

if(!isEmpty('plusTitle') && !isEmpty('plustags') && !isEmpty('plustory')) {
  console.log('none is empty');
}
```

Comment: Not using comparison operator

Answer (score 0):

considering "let" is being used, I assume you have ES6 support.
You can use below code after pushing these values to an array:

```
   let a = $('#plustitle').val().trim();  // input type text
   let b = $('#plustags').val().trim(); // input type text
   let c = $('#plustory').val().trim(); // textarea 
   let someValues = [a, b, c]; // if separate variables are not required, directly push to array   
   someValues.forEach(x =>{ if(!x) {
       //do operation when empty
   }});
```

Comment: `if ([a, b, c].some(x => !x)) {...}`

Comment: OP doesn't want to use loop as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Join all variables and check length of result

```js
let a = $('#plustitle').val().trim();
let b = $('#plustags').val().trim();
let c = $('#plustory').val().trim(); 

if ((a+b+c).length == 0)
  console.log("empty");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="plustitle" value="">
<input type="text" id="plustags" value="">
<input type="text" id="plustory" value="">
```

Also you can simplify your code and use one selector

```
var values = $('#plustitle, #plustags, #plustory').map(
  (i, ele) => ele.value.trim()
).toArray().join('');

if (values.length == 0)
  console.log("empty");
```

```js
var values = $('#plustitle, #plustags, #plustory').map(
  (i, ele) => ele.value.trim()
).toArray().join('');

if (values.length == 0)
  console.log("empty");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="plustitle" value="">
<input type="text" id="plustags" value="">
<input type="text" id="plustory" value="">
```

Comment: _"Also you can simplify your code"_ - Only if puerto doesn't need the values. Otherwise you would have to get them twice from the DOM